# How to log in remotely with AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome-extension

I'm making a [[image]google-chrome-extension](/questions/tagged/google-chrome-extension) for a certain website, and want the [`browser_action`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction) to display the number of notifications a user has received on said website.

Currently, I am using an ajax request to retrieve the HTML from the `website/messages` page, and then I am using jQuery to count the number of `"#unread > li"` elements in that HTML (each one representing a new message.)

Now, I take this number and display it on the `browser_action` icon.

All works perfectly, the correct amount of messages are notified, **BUT** the user *must* be logged in on the site (not my site) for it to work properly, otherwise they will think that they have no messages.

I was thinking that I could detect if the user is logged in, and if not display a red `!` exclamation mark on the icon. Then, when the user clicks to show the pop-up, it asks them to log in.

[image: <!><br>you must log in to get messages<br>username:<br>password<br>]

However, I have no idea how to actually log the user in to the website using this method: how do I send the credentials across? Or does the website have to support a request like this?

### TL;DR

How can I log a user into a website I don't own remotely?

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer:** I've never done a google chrome extension, but based on the rest of your question, it sounds like it's just working with JavaScript like any other web page, so I'll go ahead and answer it.

In any case, working with cookies in JavaScript can be somewhat of a pain:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie

http://www.perlscriptsjavascripts.com/js/cookies.html

I'm assuming that your server side already works with and expects cookies, so I won't try to suggest any alternatives.  That being the case, your server is what needs to validate the cookie, so, IMHO, might as well set the cookie on the server side.  If the server handles it, on the JS side, you simply post the username/password to a server-side page, e.g.

```
$.post("/user/login",{"Username":"foo","Password":"bar"},callback);
```

That server-side page validates the username/password and then, if successful, generates the cookie and sends a response back to the JavaScript (e.g. {"IsSuccess":true}).  Upon receiving a successful response rather than an error, you just start calling the other web services to retrieve your data assuming you are logged in and build out the page.

Assuming that your web services will return HTTP error codes that help you determine a problem with the session, if you get a 401 error code, you take the user back to the login page.  If you get a 403 error code, you let the user know they can't access that data...etc., all depending on your app.

Ultimately, JavaScript doesn't know whether a user is actually logged in, so you have to rely on the server to send you information in a way that is understandable so that you can direct/prompt the user as necessary.

**[Edit: 2014-11-21]**

You didn't answer my other question: what do you get back? If they don't set the cookie themselves at the login, then you need to get back the session token from the response they send...if they don't send you a session ID, you're SOL.  If they do send you an session token/session ID, then you need to know what to name it (e.g. PHP uses something like PHPSESSID as the cookie name, but it can be whatever the coders of that domain decided on).  Beyond that, you have to be able to set the cookie for THAT domain name (3rd party cookie). This may have mixed results depending on the user's settings--if they block 3rd party cookies--however, since this is a google extension and not a website, maybe it's able to bypass that kind of restriction. I know that FireFox's developer toolbar is able to manipulate cookies for all domains, so it would be a reasonable assumption you would be able to as well.

Comment: Thanks! That's opened my eyes a lot! But, the thing is, I don't actually own the server. Is there no way of "injecting" a cookie into a web page?

Comment: @minseong, does the server actually require a cookie or a token?  If they require a cookie, it seems hard to believe that they wouldn't create it themselves since they have to authenticate the user.  When you login, and it's successful, what do you get back?  Do you get a token back?  Are you sure that's supposed to be a cookie and not in the URL (e.g. ?token=XYZ)

Comment: I am 100% sure it requires a cookie.

Comment: Your answer has been very eye-opening and worthwhile, awesome amount of information! I've come up with another way of doing it though, after realising that cookies will not work.

Comment: @minseong, okay, glad you figured it out. You should enter your answer in as a second answer, and then select your own answer as the right one so that it doesn't remain "unanswered." Then, the next person that comes along trying to fix the same problem will be able to learn from your solution.

Comment: I know. I still have to wait a bit though.